# How these two functions are equivalent?

Tags: javascript, first-class-functions

I am reading a book Mostly adequate guide and in the chapter about First Class functions, I have come across this example. Can somebody explain it to me?

It says the below two lines are equal.

```
// ignorant
const getServerStuff = callback => ajaxCall(json => callback(json));

// enlightened
const getServerStuff = ajaxCall;
```

Here is the reason both are equivalent:

```
// this line
ajaxCall(json => callback(json));

// is the same as this line
ajaxCall(callback);

// so refactor getServerStuff
const getServerStuff = callback => ajaxCall(callback);

// ...which is equivalent to this
const getServerStuff = ajaxCall; // <-- look mum, no ()'s
```

But I can't undertand this part. How are these two equivalent?

```
// this line
ajaxCall(json => callback(json));

// is the same as this line
ajaxCall(callback);
```

Can someone please explain it in layman terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're equivalent because the first line introduces an anonymous function that does nothing except forward its argument to `callback`, and return `callback`'s return value.

Generally speaking, a function `x` that does nothing except for forward its arguments to some other function `y` and return the result, can be replaced by the inner `y` function. `x` isn't doing anything meaningful.

So, given a function `x`...

```
function x(arg) { return y(arg) }
```

Here we define a function `x`. The purpose of `x` is to accept an argument `arg` and invoke `y(arg)`. However, we already have means of invoking `y(arg)` if we have `y`, and we have `arg`:  **By simply invoking `y(arg)`**.  We don't need to introduce a new function `x` for this purpose.

---

It's worth noting that the two lines in your question are only equivalent when `ajaxCall` invokes its callback with one argument. For them to be *truly* equal, the first line would need to forward all arguments:

```
ajaxCall(...json => callback(...json));
```